# scriptNode.onaudioprocess is deprecated , any alternative?

Tags: javascript, audio, buffer, html5-audio, audiocontext

I want to get the audio buffer while talking , I did this method to detect it , but I receive message this method onaudioprocess is deprecated and is not fired, is there any alternative for it with an example.

```js
audioContext = new AudioContext({ sampleRate: 16000 });
scriptNode = (audioContext.createScriptProcessor || audioContext.createJavaScriptNode).call(audioContext, 1024, 1, 1);
scriptNode.onaudioprocess = function (audioEvent) {
  if (recording) {
    input = audioEvent.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
    // convert float audio data to 16-bit PCM
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(input.length * 2);
    var output = new DataView(buffer);
    for (var i = 0, offset = 0; i < input.length; i++, offset += 2) {
      var s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, input[i]));
      output.setInt16(offset, s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7fff, true);
    }
    ws.send(buffer);
  }
};
```

Comment: How are you capturing your audio? Are you intending to capture the sound from your microphone and send it to a websocket?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier   yes, it's from my microphone to a websocket .

Comment: Could you give some feedback on the answer below?

Answer (score 4):

**Sidenote**: Although my earlier answer did help some people, it didn't provide an alternative to the [deprecated `onaudioprocess` event and ScriptProcessorNode Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode/onaudioprocess). This is answer should provide an alternative to the question by OP.

The answer should be using [Audio Worklets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorklet) with enables us to create *custom audio processing nodes* to which can implemented like a regular [`AudioNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode).

> The AudioWorkletNode interface of the Web Audio API represents a base class for a user-defined AudioNode, which can be connected to an audio routing graph along with other nodes. It has an associated AudioWorkletProcessor, which does the actual audio processing in a Web Audio rendering thread.

It works by extending the [`AudioWorkletProcessor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor) class and providing the mandatory [`process`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor/process) method. The `process` method exposes the `inputs`, `outputs` and `parameters` set in the static [parameterDescriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor/parameterDescriptors) getter.

In here you can insert the same logic as in the `onaudioprocess` callback. But you do have to make some modifications to work properly.

One catch of using worklets is that you have include this script as a file from the worklets interface. This means that any dependencies, like the `ws` variable, needs to be injected at later stage. We can extend the class to add any values or dependencies to the instance of the worklet.

**Note:** The `process` needs to [return a boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor/process#return_value) to let the browser know if the audio node should be kept alive or not.

```
registerProcessor('buffer-detector', class extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
  process (inputs, outputs, parameters) {
    if (this.#socket === null) {
      return false;
    }

    if (this.#isRecording === true) {
      const [input] = inputs;
      const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(input.length * 2);
      const output = new DataView(buffer);

      for (let i = 0, offset = 0; i < input.length; i++, offset += 2) {
        const s = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, input[i]));
        output.setInt16(offset, s < 0 ? s * 0x8000 : s * 0x7fff, true);
      }

      this.#socket.send(buffer);
    }

    return true;
  }

  static get parameterDescriptors() {
    return [{
      name: 'Buffer Detector',
    }]
  }

  #socket = null;
  #isRecording = false;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  get socket() {
    return this.#socket;
  }

  set socket(value) {
    if (value instanceof WebSocket) {
      this.#socket = value;
    }
  }

  get recording() {
    return this.#isRecording;
  }

  set recording(value) {
    if ('boolean' === typeof value) {
      this.#isRecording = value;
    }
  }
});
```

Now all we have to do is include the worklet in your script and create an instance of the node. We can do this with the [`addModule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worklet/addModule) method that exists on the `BaseAudioContext.audioWorklet` property.

*Important:* Adding the module **only** works in secure (HTTPS) contexts.

When the module has been added successfully, create the new node with the [`AudioWorkletNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletNode) constructor. Assign the WebSocket instance, set the recording flag and you're good to go.

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://...');
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const source = new MediaStreamAudioSourceNode(audioContext, {
  mediaStream: stream // Your stream here.
});

(async () => {
  try {
    // Register the worklet.
    await audioContext.audioWorklet.addModule('buffer-detector.js');

    // Create our custom node.
    const bufferDetectorNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audioContext, 'buffer-detector');

    // Assign the socket and the recording state.
    bufferDetectorNode.socket = ws;
    bufferDetectorNode.recording = true;

    // Connect the node.
    source.connect(bufferDetectorNode);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Hey @emiel-zuurbier, how is setting `bufferDetectorNode.recording` passing the value to `this._isRecording`. I was testing this example and it does not seem to work.

Comment: @EX0MAK3R That was a typo on my end. The `recording` setter wasn't properly defined in the class. Try it again with the modified code above.

Answer (score 3):

With the [MediaStream Recording API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API) and the [`MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) method you're able to stream audio from your microphone and stream that into a recorder. The recorder can then send `Blob` objects through WebSockets whenever the [`ondataavailable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/ondataavailable) event fires on the recorder.

The function below creates a stream and passes that to a [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) instance. That instance will record your microphone audio and is able to send that to your WebSocket. The instance of the `MediaRecorder` is returned to control the recorder.

```
async function streamMicrophoneAudioToSocket(ws) {
  let stream;
  const constraints = { video: false, audio: true };

  try {
    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`
      MediaDevices.getUserMedia() threw an error. 
      Stream did not open.
      ${error.name} - 
      ${error.message}
    `);
  }

  const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

  recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', ({ data }) => {
    ws.send(data);
  });

  recorder.start();
  return recorder;
});
```

That way you can also **stop** recording if you'd like by calling the [`stop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/stop) method on the recorder.

```
(async () => {
  const ws = new WebSocket('ws://yoururl.com');
  const recorder = await streamMicrophoneAudioToSocket(ws);

  document.addEventListener('click', event => {
    recorder.stop();
  });
}());
```

Comment: can we directly send stream audio from microphone to server ?  does recording the stream mandatory ?

Comment: I'm sure it is possible, but I haven't built such an implementation yet. In the (near) future we might have the [WebSocketStream API](https://web.dev/websocketstream/) which will make streaming audio and video a lot easier.

Comment: thanks for the reply, will try to implement it